# Ember 2 select dependency

Tags: javascript, select, ember.js

I'm trying to create a depency between two select boxes in ember.
I found a solution for an older version of ember:
http://jsbin.com/cibonulora/1/edit

But with the new version and with a complete model with json+rest, i can´t seem to get it working.
http://jsbin.com/jumiwogugi/4/edit?html,js,console,output

When i select one item in the checkbox it should filter the elements on the second. but nothing happens.

Thanks

My code:

```
App = Ember.Application.create({});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController : function(controller, model) {
        this._super(controller, model);
      controller.set('producttypes', this.store.find('producttype'));
    }
});





App.ProducttypesController = Ember.Object.create({
  content: null
});

App.ProductsubtypesController = Ember.Object.create({
  content: null
});


App.ProductsubtypeController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  active: function() {
    alert(""); }.property("App.selectedProductType.content").cacheable()
});







//model

App.Producttype = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr(),
});

App.Productsubtype = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr(),
});

var producttypes = {
  "producttypes":[
    {"id":1,"name":"type1"},
    {"id":2,"name":"type2"},
    {"id":3,"name":"type3"}   
  ]  
};
var productsubtypes = {
  "productsubtypes":[
    {"id":4,"name":"type4","type_id":"1"},
    {"id":5,"name":"type5","type_id":"1"},
    {"id":6,"name":"type6","type_id":"3"}   
  ]  
};

$.mockjax({
    url:  '/producttypes',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'get',
    responseText: producttypes
});
$.mockjax({
    url:  '/productsubtypes',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'get',
    responseText: productsubtypes
});
```

Comment: Did you mean dependency? Also please include the relevant code snippets directly in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for my problem.

The controller:

```
App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  selectedProductTypeChanged: function(){
    var obj = this.get('selectedProductType');     
    if (obj != null) { 
      console.log(typeof obj.id);
       var unfiltered=this.get('productsubtypes');
    var filtered=this.get('productsubtypes').filterProperty("producttype",obj.id);
     this.set('filterproductsubtypes',filtered );
      this.set('selectedProductSubType',null);
    }    
  }.observes('selectedProductType')
});
```

Link to jsbin: http://jsbin.com/juvokacuno/3/edit?html,js,output